# UITapGestureRecognizer on view after CGAffineTransformScale

Tags: swift, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIImageView with a UITapGestureRecognizer attached to it. The tap gesture responds normally and everything works at first, but the view is also scaled dynamically at runtime by a CGAffineTransform. After the scaling operation, only the original bounds of the view respond to the touch event. I need the new scaled bounds of the view to respond to the touch event.

Code for UIImageView setup:

```
    --- rest of view and imageView setup ---
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AAImageView.imageTapped))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.addSubview(imageView)
```

Code for CGAffineTransform:

```
        let annotationView = mapView.view(for: annotation) {
            // Calculate the modification scale factor from the map GSD and scaled image GSD
            let factor = CGFloat(initialMetersPerPoint / mapView.metersPerPoint(atLatitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude))
            // Scale and rotate the image appropriately to maintain position on the map.
            annotationView.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: factor, y: factor).rotated(by: MGLRadiansFromDegrees(-mapView.direction))
        }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I tested your case, the tap gesture still works as it should even after scaling the imageView, if I tapped on any point at the scaled imageView it fired... are you sure that the reason of the issue is the scaling?

Comment: I guess one part that I didn't mention in the post is that the imageView is a subview of a view that is not being scaled, so I guess the issue is probably that the tap gestures aren't being recognized outside the bounds of it's superview?